# Two objects are equal, but js does say false.

Tags: javascript, object

I have object whose (`JSON.stringify`) looks like:

```
"{"test":[{"header":{"test":1}}]}"
```

and another object which looks like:

```
"{"test":1}"
```

Now if I try this:

```
firstObj.test[0].header == secondObj
```

javascript says `false`. Why?

Comment: totally agree with @dfsq, only add you can compare inner primitive types (`string` and `int`) to simulate the comparation and obtain `true` if needed, ask if you need more info to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript two objects (e.i. objects, arrays, functions - all non-primitive types) are equal only if they are the **same** objects, otherwise even if they look the same, have same properties and values - they are different objects and there is no way comparing them would give you `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript compares non-primitives by reference, Two references cannot be same.

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
```

then

```
a == b //true
```

Similar case for Arrays, Functions

Answer (score 0):

As others here point out, object comparison in JS is same-instance comparison, not value comparison. For your limited example, comparing instead the results of JSON.stringify() would seem to work, but if you cannot guarantee the order of properties (which JS does not), then that won't work either. See [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) for details. That link has a more intricate answer, but if you know the objects you're comparing then the best test of comparison is a specific one IMHO, e.g. test for the properties you care about. Objects can be anything in JS, therefore, thinking of objects as being "equal" does not make sense outside a specific context.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:1}) !== JSON.stringify({b:1,a:1})` Comparing objects using `JSON.stringify` is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, that's why I linked to an answer which explains these limitations. I'll edit my answer to mention this, but without more context from the OP it is hard to give a general answer.